# StampedTransform getting Position instead of Relative Position

Tags: ros, rviz, position, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

HI,
I am trying to log some data. The code works like intended except I am receiving the Relative Position instead of the Position.

```
tf::StampedTransform transformOdom;
current_time = ros::Time::now();

try {
        listener.waitForTransform( "odom","base_footprint", ros::Time(0), ros::Duration(10.0));
    listener.lookupTransform( "odom", "base_footprint",ros::Time(0), transformOdom);
    }
    catch (tf::TransformException &ex) {
        ROS_ERROR("%s",ex.what());
    }

//For debugging purposes
ROS_INFO_STREAM("X pose " <<  transformOdom.getOrigin().x() );
ROS_INFO_STREAM("Y pose " << transformOdom.getOrigin().y());

fileToWrite.open ("log.txt", ios_base::app);
fileToWrite << "X: " << transformOdom.getOrigin().x() << " Y: " << transformOdom.getOrigin().y()<< "\n";
fileToWrite.close();
```

[image: Here is where you can see the two different positions from the visualization software]

Does anyone know how to get the position of the robot instead of the relative position?

Thanks,
choog

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/202130/stampedtransform-getting-position-instead-of-relative-position/) by [choog](https://answers.ros.org/users/18787/choog/) on ROS Answers with karma: 101 on 2015-01-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to choose a frame that you consider fixed, e.g., /map.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2015-01-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [choog](https://answers.ros.org/users/18787/choog/) on 2015-01-30**:
listener.waitForTransform( "map","base_footprint", ros::Time(0), ros::Duration(10.0));
listener.lookupTransform( "map", "base_footprint",ros::Time(0), transformOdom);

as such?

**Comment by [choog](https://answers.ros.org/users/18787/choog/) on 2015-01-30**:
That worked. I figured that is what you meant and it tried. Thanks a lot.

**Comment by [Henschel.X](https://answers.ros.org/users/26183/henschel.x/) on 2016-03-21**:
Hi! I met the same problem just like you, I changed "odom" with "map", instead, I got this error
**"map" passed to lookupTransform argument target_frame does not exist.**
Can you tell me what should I do ? I don't even know what odom means. CuzI just started to learn ROS  ;(,Thx anyway